# Data from html is not displayed in php files and sent as empty mail

Tags: php, jquery, html, email

I couldn't bring data from html pages into php. I was testing it for whole day, but I'm stuck on this issue. could you please help me? Thank you and appreciate for your kind help. Below is my code ....

service.html

```
<div class="accordion-inner">
  <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
  <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="requestquote.php" role="form">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span5" style="text-align: left;">
        <label>FULL NAME</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your Full Name" tabindex="1">
        <label>COMPANY (OPTIONAL)</label>
        <input type="text" name="cname" id="cname" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Your Company Name" tabindex="2">
        <label>EMAIL </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your Email Address" tabindex="3">
        <label>PHONE</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your Phone" tabindex="4">
      </div>
      <div class="span7" style="text-align: left;">
        <label>SOLUTIONS</label>

        <select name="category" id="category">                                
                                        <option value="">Please Select…</option>
                                        <option value="Web Design and Development">Web Design and Development</option>
                                        <option value="Mobile Application Development">Mobile Application Development</option>
                                        <option value="Networking Services & Consultancy">Networking Services &amp; Consultancy</option>
                                        <option value="Hotel Management Solution ">Hotel Management Solution </option>                                   
                                        <option value="IT Help Desk Service ">IT Help Desk Service </option>
                                    </select>
        <label>YOUR IDEAS (OR) MESSAGE </label>
        <textarea name="message1" id="message1" required="required" class="input-block-level1" rows="10" tabindex="5"></textarea>
      </div>

    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="sendmsg" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right" value="Send Message">
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

requestquote.php

```
<?php 

header('Content-type: application/json');
$status = array(
    'type'=>'success',
    'message'=>'Thank you for contacting us!, '
);

$fname = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['fname'])); 
$cname = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['cname'])); 
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$phone = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone']));
$category = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['category']));        
$message1 = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message1'])); 

$email_from = $email;
$email_to = "musicalbum01@gmail.com";

$from = "ymphyow@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;

$Body = 'First Name: ' . $fname . "\n \n " .'Company Name: ' . $cname . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\n\n" . 'category: ' . $category . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message1; 

$success = @mail($email_to,"Request a free quotation", $Body, $headers);

$thankyou = "Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you shortly.";
@mail($email_from," Request a free quotation ",  $thankyou, $headers);


 if( $success == true ){
        echo json_encode($status); 
        die;
 } else { 
        echo json_encode(" Failed "); 
 }
```

?>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815710/why-is-phps-mail-function-successfully-sending-mail-but-with-blank-fields

Comment: What is this for: header('Content-type: application/json'); I never use such ..

Comment: And you should not supress errors:@mail($email_from is beter like mail($email_from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use this instead of your `$headers` variable :

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'From: ymphyow <ymphyow@gmail.com>';
```

check the [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

also please check the similar question [Why is php's mail() function successfully sending mail but with blank fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815710/why-is-phps-mail-function-successfully-sending-mail-but-with-blank-fields)

Comment: please try those headers instead
$headers[] .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers[] .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\r\n"; 

i just tried and works perfectly , seems like you need the \r\n to work ;)

Comment: Thank you so much.